# Overlapping area rectangle in SceneKit on Collision

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to find the contacted area (overlapping area rectangle) between two object on collision. In Scenekit I am getting a callback on collision `physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact)`.

`SCNPhysicsContact` has `contactPoint`, `contactNormal`, `penetrationDistance`. I am not able to get contacted area between two objects. More info about `SCNPhysicsContact` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicscontact

How to calculate the overlapping area rectangle on collision between `nodeA` and `nodeB`?